# cannot find -lqwtE

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, qt4.8

i succesfully

- compiled qt 4.8.6 using arm-linux-gnueabihf-
- compiled qwt 6.0.0 except qwtsvg, qwtdesigner, qwtmath, qwtexamples
- and copied qwt-bin (compiled path of qwt) features to my qt features
  directory.

after those, i tried to compile my project, but i got an error about "cannot find -lqwtE". i dont understand why i got this error, all paths correct, i didnt get this error when i'm compiling in target machine.

Output of project compile:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qt-arm/lib -o p main.o #object files removed by me#    -L/opt/qt-arm/lib -lQtSerialPortE -L/opt/projects/p/trunk/qwt-bin/lib -lqwtE -lQtDeclarativeE -L/opt/qt-arm/lib -lQtScriptE -lQtSqlE -lQtGuiE -lQtNetworkE -lQtCoreE -lpthread
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -lqwtE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [p] Error 1
```

any help appreciated!
m.

Comment: It cannot find `-lqwtE` because *you don't have a file named libqwtE.a or libqwtE.so with the correct architecture in your library search path*. If you think the italicized sentence is incorrect, try to demonstrate the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E tag added by qt cause its compiled as embedded. all libraries have E tag. but qwt is third party library and cant resolve that. so, i removed E tag from project's Makefile and problem solved.

thanks for any interests